# Problema con django-bootstrap3

Tags: python, django, bootstrap, django-forms

Tengo instalado Django 1.11 y django-bootstrap3 en su versión 8.2.3 mediante pip. Estoy haciendo una aplicación sencilla que lleva un formulario. Revisando la documentación online vi que hay que agregar en el settings.py la configuración del Bootstrap 3 como sigue:

```
BOOTSTRAP3 = {

    'jquery_url': '//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js',
    'base_url': '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/',
    'css_url': None,
    'theme_url': None,
    'javascript_url': None,
    'javascript_in_head': False,
    'include_jquery': False,
    'horizontal_label_class': 'col-md-3',
    'horizontal_field_class': 'col-md-9',
    'set_required': True,
    'set_disabled': False,
    'set_placeholder': True,
    'required_css_class': '',
    'error_css_class': 'has-error',
    'success_css_class': 'has-success',
    'formset_renderers':{
        'default': 'bootstrap3.renderers.FormsetRenderer',
    },
    'form_renderers': {
        'default': 'bootstrap3.renderers.FormRenderer',
    },
    'field_renderers': {
        'default': 'bootstrap3.renderers.FieldRenderer',
        'inline': 'bootstrap3.renderers.InlineFieldRenderer',
    },
}
```

Pero cuando trabajo offline mi aplicación no me carga los CSS ni los JavaScript porque mi configuración esta apuntando a este sitio:

```
'base_url': '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/',
```

El Bootstrap lo tengo instalado en esta ruta de mi computadora:

```
/home/pavel/.virtualenvs/pavel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bootstrap3
```

Como pueden ver estoy utilizando un entorno virtual.

Mi pregunta es ¿Como configuro en el `settings.py` para que mi aplicación cargue el bootstrap3 local en vez de cargarlo desde la Internet?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la solución en Django está en los static files, al final los archivos de bootstrap deben estar disponibles en el servidor web, para ello deberemos darle una url pueda resolver.

Echa un vistazo a este [enlace de la documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/)